# How can I add numbers to specific equations in an eqnarray*?

Tags: equations, numbering

I know how to use `\nonumber` or `\notag`  in `\begin{eqnarray}` `\end{eqnarray}` environment.

But is there something like `\addnumber` or `\addtag` in `\begin{eqnarray*}` `\end{eqnarray*}` environment ?

For example, if I want only the second equation below be tagged, what should I do?

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
a &=& b\\ 
c &=& d  \addnumber\\ 
e &=& f\\
g &=& h\\
i &=& j
\end{eqnarray*}
```

Comment: For some reason \\ shows like \ above.

Comment: a tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they're marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). Then the "\\" shows as it should. (Leo did this for you.)

Comment: Do not use `eqnarray`: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=eqnarray

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
a &= b\\ 
c &= d  \addtag \\ 
e &= f\\
g &= h\\
i &= j
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that Leo replaced `eqnarray` with `align`, [which is the recommended thing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align/197#197).

Comment: I'm _sure_ there's already a command defined by `amsmath` that does exactly this... But I can't remember what it's called.

Comment: @Seamus: I tried to find it in `amsmath` and `mathtools`, but failed.

Comment: @Leo That's weird. I was totally convinced I'd done something like this before... Oh well, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: @Seamus: This is almost how standard LaTeX does: use `\refstepcounter` to set the counter and cross reference, and output the number. Maybe this command should be put into `mathtools`.

Comment: @Leo Yeah I assumed that that was pretty much what the macro would do, if it existed. Does this solution play nice with hyperref?

Comment: @Seamus: Yes. Use `\label` *after* `\addtag`. `hyperref` just redefine `\refstepcounter` etc.