# Giving an equation between \[ \]'s a number

Tags: math-mode, equations, numbering

I usually use `\[ ... \]` to typeset equations in latex and sometimes I come back and realize that I want to have an equation number and label. I have been coming back and editing it to `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}` but this is annoying and time consuming. Is there a command to do something like `\[ \addeqnumber{} \]` which will work the same way as the equation environment? I am aware this probably isn't the best practice, but it would save me some annoyance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\addtag{\refstepcounter{equation}\tag{\theequation}}

\begin{document}

\[
  1+1=2  \addtag
\]

\end{document}
```

See also:
[How can I add numbers to specific equations in an eqnarray*?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10379/equation-numbering-question)

Answer (score 8):

If you find yourself doing this for *all* equations I would use search & replace but if you’re reluctant you can do the following:

```
\let\[\equation
\let\]\endequation
```

After that, `\[ … \]` will behave identical to `\begin{equation} … \end{equation}`.

You can also wrap this into a macro, and create another one to switch back so that you can switch between the two styles via two macros.

Comment: This won't handle the numbering appropriately if the `amsmath` package is loaded.

Comment: @Gonzalo Hmm, weird. What’s the issue?

Comment: If you load `amsmath` and use your suggestion, all the equations written with `\[...\]` will receive the same numbering: (1).

Comment: this should use `\begin` etc., see the last few lines of `amsmath.sty`

Comment: I'm using `amsmath` and this is working just fine...

Answer (score 8):

Not answering your question but maybe solving your problem: `mathtools` has a mechanism that suppresses equation numbers for unreferenced equations. (So you'd always use equation and friends and only get numbers if you ref the equation.)

Answer (score 3):

As you're aware that this isn't best practice, I don't mind answering!  The following seems to work:

```
\newcommand{\addlabel}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{equation}%
\label{#1}%
\let\]\endequation}
```

Use it as:

```
\[
\addlabel{pythagoras}
x^2 + y^2 = z^2
\]
```

The start of `\equation` simply steps the counter, so we do that and don't have to worry about doing anything else at the begining.  Then we assign the label (since there's no point in having one command to add the number and then *another* to assign a label to it).  To place the label, we use the `\endequation` command.  As we're doing this *inside* the mathematics, the assignment `\let\]\endequation` only holds until the end of the mathematics and so it doesn't affect future mathematics (which is a bit lucky for future mathematics).

Comment: This doesn't work if `amsmath` is loaded.

Comment: And there's a typo in the definition of `\addlabel`: it should be `\label{#1}`, instead of `\label{pythagoras}`.

Comment: @Gonzalo: (amsmath) Probably not, but the question didn't specify a package and was clearly not looking for a "robust" solution so I didn't spend much effort on it.  (pythagoras) Whoops!  That was my test case.  Still, Leo's looks simplest so I'll not bother sorting out the problems with mine!

Answer (score 3):

To build on Konrad's answer and make it work with `amsmath`, I'd use:

```
\newcommand{\myequation}{\begin{equation}}
\newcommand{\myendequation}{\end{equation}}
\let\[\myequation
\let\]\myendequation
```

Comment: This is the best answer. No need to type :"\addtag"

Comment: Note that there's a pitfall if you use this for `align`: [environments - What is wrong with defining \bal as \begin{align}? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100138/what-is-wrong-with-defining-bal-as-beginalign)