# Enumeration of equations in the double dollar math mode

Tags: equations, numbering, environments

How introduce enumeration of equations in the double dollar math mode (i.e. `$$...$$`)?

Or even better, is it possible to make `$$...$$` as a particular math environment, e.g. `equation` or `align`?

Comment: I believe that `$$...$$` is depricated in LaTeX.

Comment: @A.Ellett Thanks, good to know. But since I'm using a lot of equations, (usually) in the same environment, I was curious how to make it more human-readable.

Comment: Indeed, you should not use `$$...$$`: have a look at this question [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to)

Comment: There is a helpful program for getting rid of $$ signs, due to Andrew Stacey: http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/HowDidIDoThat/LaTeX/debuck.html

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay Technically, getting rid of `$$` is simple. However, I still use them for UX purposes - `\[` does interfere with looking at an equation, while `$$` does not (brackets are very common and dollars are very rare in typical mathematical typesetting).

Comment: The script that Benjamin McKay links to has moved.  It is now at https://github.com/loopspace/debuck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, do not use double dollars for display mathematics.  I teach freshman math students to use LaTeX for all homeworks and projects during sophomore-senior years and they are taught not to use double dollars for display mathematics for two of many reasons.
1) It is no longer considered the correct (current) way to delineate display mathematics
2) If is not in line with 'best practices' as there are a number of situations where they do not work correctly (or as expected)

Second to answer the question which should have been:
"How do I number equations delineated by `\[...\]` ?"  I searched this site for 'numbering equations' and found this reference: [Giving an equation between \[ \]'s a number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/giving-an-equation-between-s-a-number)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit unclear, but based on this :

> But since I'm using a lot of equations, (usually) in the same environment, I was curious how to make it more human-readable.

I assume you want to list several equations within the pair of `\[` and `\]`.

If so, you can use the `amsmath` package and its subenvironments such as `gathered` :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some blabla here...
\[
\begin{gathered}
  1+1=2 \\
  2+2=4
\end{gathered}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]