# Problem using aligned

Tags: math-mode, equations, align, amsmath

This MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    
    $$\begin{aligned}
        \Gamma_{11}^1  & =0, \qquad \Gamma_{12}^1  & =0, \qquad \Gamma_{22}^1  & =-\frac{1}{2}G_u, \\
        G\Gamma_{11}^2 & =0, \qquad G\Gamma_{12}^2 & =\frac{1}{2}G_u, \qquad G\Gamma_{22}^2 & =0. 
    \end{aligned}$$
    
\end{document}
```

Generates: [image]

and I can't understand why is the middle `&` not working, I've used it in the same way as the first and last `&`.

Comment: Add one `&` before each `\qquad`. And [please replace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85346/47927) `$$`...`$$` by `\[`...`\]`.

Comment: Better yet, `\begin{align*}`, rather than `aligned` within `\[`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since it seems to be a common question how to correctly place ampersands in alignment environments in math, maybe it helps to illustrate it like this:

In a lot of alignment environments for math (for example `align`, `aligned`, `alignat` etc.), each ampersand introduces a new column and each double backslash introduces a new row. In each row, every first column is right-aligned and every second column is left-aligned.

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}\footnotesize

    \[\begin{aligned}
        \fbox{one\strut} & \fbox{two\strut} \\
        \fbox{right-aligned\strut} & \fbox{left-aligned\strut} 
    \end{aligned}\]
    
    \bigskip
    
    \[\begin{aligned}
        \fbox{one\strut} & \fbox{two\strut} & \fbox{three\strut} & \fbox{four\strut} & \fbox{five\strut} & \fbox{six\strut} \\
        \fbox{right-aligned\strut} & \fbox{left-aligned\strut} & \fbox{right-aligned\strut} & \fbox{left-aligned\strut} & \fbox{right-aligned\strut} & \fbox{left-aligned\strut} 
    \end{aligned}\]

    \bigskip
    
    \[\begin{aligned}
        \fbox{one\strut} & \fbox{two\strut} & \fbox{three\strut} & \fbox{four\strut} & \fbox{five\strut} & \fbox{six\strut} \\
        \Gamma_{11}^1  & =0, &\qquad \Gamma_{12}^1  & =0, &\qquad \Gamma_{22}^1  & =-\frac{1}{2}G_u, \\
        G\Gamma_{11}^2 & =0, & G\Gamma_{12}^2 & =\frac{1}{2}G_u, & G\Gamma_{22}^2 & =0. 
    \end{aligned}\]
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you switch to an `alignedat` environment and place the `\qquad` directives on the second line. I would also use `\tfrac` rather than `\frac`, in order to reduce the visual prominence of the fraction terms.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{alignedat}{3}
  \Gamma_{\!11}^1 &=0,       &  \Gamma_{\!12}^1 &=0,                      &  \Gamma_{\!22}^1  &=-\tfrac{1}{2}G_u, \\
 G\Gamma_{\!11}^2 &=0,\qquad & G\Gamma_{\!12}^2 &=\tfrac{1}{2}G_u, \qquad & G\Gamma_{\!22}^2  &=0 \,. 
\end{alignedat}
\]  
\end{document}
```

---

Or, use a single `alignat*` environment instead of the `\[ \begin{alignedat}{3} ... \end{alignedat} \]` combination:

```
\begin{alignat*}{3}
  \Gamma_{\!11}^1 &=0,       &  \Gamma_{\!12}^1 &=0,                      &  \Gamma_{\!22}^1  &=-\tfrac{1}{2}G_u, \\
 G\Gamma_{\!11}^2 &=0,\qquad & G\Gamma_{\!12}^2 &=\tfrac{1}{2}G_u, \qquad & G\Gamma_{\!22}^2  &=0 \,. 
\end{alignat*}
```