# Align two columns of equations

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I wrote this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \cos x, \qquad h(x) = -x, \\
g(x) &= x, \qquad l(x) = \sin x.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

I got this result:

[image]

What do I have to change for the equal signs in the right column to be also aligned (note that I want to conserve the labels as they are)?

Comment: In that post, the numeration of the equations is not mantained.

Comment: This answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590213 has a helpful diagram.  When used with `align` (no `*`) that should give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is typically done in an `align` with the introduction of additional `&`'s:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
  f(x) &= \cos x, & h(x) &= -x,     \\
  g(x) &= x,      & l(x) &= \sin x.
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\end{document}
```

The equations are spread horizontally automatically. You can have multiple such constructions on a single line.