# How to use the & symbol in the alignedat environnment?

Tags: alignment, alignat

I'm having trouble understanding how to use the `&` symbol in most of the alignment environnments, in particular in the alignedat environnment.

I'm trying to align some `\Rightarrow` and equal signs but here is what I get :

[image]

I want to align the `\Rightarrow` with the green line while keeping the alignment on the red and blue line. I thought that the `&` was seperating the columns but, obviously it does more than this.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]
        $\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
            &Q(t)=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} \\
            &\frac{Q_0}{2}=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} &\Rightarrow e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = \frac{1}{2} \\
            &&\Rightarrow \frac{-t}{RC}=-\ln(2) \\
            &&\Rightarrow t&=\ln(2)\cdot RC \\
            &&&=\ln(2)\cdot \SI{6.20e-9}{\second} \\
            &&&=\SI{4.30e-9}{\second} \\
        \end{alignedat}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Maybe of some help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/590213/47927

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make use of `\mathrlap`, which hides the width of it parameter so that subsequent alignment points are not affected.

Also, each `&` provides a `r`ight/`l`eft alignment. That is, the content on the left of the `&` is `r`ight aligned and the content on the right of it is `l`eft aligned.  Only use those where needed.

[image]

If you really want the first two lines to be left aligned (and *not* aligned on the `=` sign), then you have to skip past the first alignment point and also adjust all subsequent alignment points as well:

[image]

In this case, as the second line is left aligned, the first line sticks out further, thus pushing out the `\Rightarrow` horizontally to the right. If that additional space is not not desired you can apply `mathrlap` on the first line:

```
&Q(t) = \mathrlap{Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}} \\
```

### Code: `Aligned at = at Start`

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]
        $\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
            Q(t) = Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} \\
            \frac{Q_0}{2} = Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} 
                &\Rightarrow \mathrlap{e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = \frac{1}{2}} \\
                &\Rightarrow \mathrlap{\frac{-t}{RC} = -\ln(2)} \\
            &\Rightarrow t &&=\ln(2)\cdot RC \\
            &&&=\ln(2)\cdot \SI{6.20e-9}{\second} \\
            &&&=\SI{4.30e-9}{\second} \\
        \end{alignedat}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

### Code: `Left Aligned at Start`

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{xcolor}\pagecolor{white}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]
        $\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
            &Q(t) = Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} \\
            &\frac{Q_0}{2} = Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} 
                &&\Rightarrow \mathrlap{e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = \frac{1}{2}} \\
            &&&\Rightarrow \mathrlap{\frac{-t}{RC} = -\ln(2)} \\
            &&&\Rightarrow t &&=\ln(2)\cdot RC \\
            &&&&&=\ln(2)\cdot \SI{6.20e-9}{\second} \\
            &&&&&=\SI{4.30e-9}{\second} \\
        \end{alignedat}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! I was still wondering why you had to add an extra ```&``` for the second ```\Rightarrow``` in the "Left aligned" code while you didn't do it in the "Aligned at =". I also noticed that there was more space, at the second line, before the ```Rightarrow``` in the "Left aligned" code. What is it due to ? Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: In the "Left aligned" code, each `\Rightarrow` has three `&` occuring before it on the line (note where the double backslahses occur).  The first `\Rightarrow` has text between the first and the subsequent `&&`. Does that make sense?   Since the second line is left aligned, the first line sticks out further, thus pushing out the `\Rightarrow` horizontally to the right. If that is not desired apply `mathrlap` to the right hand since of the `=` on the first line.

Answer (score 6):

Just nest an `aligned`

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\setstretch{1.25}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item [(c)]
   $\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
     &Q(t)=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} \\
     &\frac{Q_0}{2}=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} 
     &&\Rightarrow e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} = \frac{1}{2} \\
     &&&\Rightarrow \frac{-t}{RC}=-\ln(2) \\
     &&&\Rightarrow \begin{aligned}[t]
       t&=\ln(2)\cdot RC \\
        &=\ln(2)\cdot \SI{6.20e-9}{\second} \\
        &=\SI{4.30e-9}{\second}
     \end{aligned}
  \end{alignedat}$
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You may want to adjust the placement of the tab stops:

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, mathtools}
\usepackage[margin=1.25in, showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\jot}{1ex}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.25}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item [(c)]
        $\begin{alignedat}[t]{3}
            Q(t)=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} \\
            \frac{Q_0}{2}=Q_0e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} &\Rightarrow & e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} &= \frac{1}{2} \\
            &\Rightarrow &\frac{-t}{RC}&=-\ln(2) \\
            &\Rightarrow &t &=\ln(2)\cdot RC \\
            &&&=\ln(2)\cdot \SI{6.20e-9}{\second} \\
            &&&=\SI{4.30e-9}{\second} \\
        \end{alignedat}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]