# how can I write equation numbers in latex?

Tags: equations, numbering

how can I write equation numbers in latex. like 1, 2, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k)
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: You don't latex does it for you. Try `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}` instead of `\[...\]`. BTW: this should be covered in any reasonable latex introduction. (BTW: I did not give this a thumb down, whoever did should have added a comment)

Comment: Also, please use examples that are possible to compile in questions. This document yields an error. (BTW: I have also not given thumbs down.)

Comment: Do please study the posting [What are the differences between `$$`, `\[`, `align`, `equation` and `displaymath`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/40492/5001)

Comment: Related question: [math mode - Giving an equation between `\[ \]`'s a number - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14705/giving-an-equation-between-s-a-number/14708#14708) (the only difference is that the linked question the OP already know a solution and ask for a shortcut)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the excellent suggestions above in comments section -- if you wish to do manual numbering add the `\tag` syntax at the end of the equation --`\tag{..3.1.1a,b} \label{myeq}` --the `\label` syntax for referencing can be plugged in if desired

Off course you can revert to auto numbering with the equation environment

And the negative points are not mine(-1)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k) \tag{..3.1.1a,b} \label{myeq}
\]

For example, see \eqref{myeq}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think it should be labelled quite strongly that for newcomers this is not a good idea. Let LaTeX handle the numbering. Otherwise we'll see users writing `\tag{1}` , `\tag{2}` ....

Comment: Observe that the OP asked about simple equation numbers such as `1` and `2`, *not* `..3.1.1a,b`.

Comment: I just had need non-default equation numbers so this answer worked well for me.

Answer (score 5):

To switch from an unnumbered to a numbered displayed equation, all you have to do is replace `\[` and `\]` with `\begin{equation}` and `\end{equation}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,geometry}
\providecommand\pdv[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\begin{document}
Unnumbered displayed equation:
\[
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k)
\]

\bigskip
Numbered displayed equation:
\begin{equation}
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k)
\end{equation} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can continue to use `\[ \]` and use the `\tag{}` to label the equation as well as the `'\label{}'` to allow it to be referenced later, or you can use `'\begin{equation}'` & `'\end{equation}'` instead so that it will automatically label the equation for you.

If you choose to use `\begin{equation}` and you would like your equation to be numbered differently, you can still use `\tag` to label it differently.

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k) \tag{1.1} \label{eq1}
\]
\end{document}
```

or,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\pdv{T^k}{t} = 
-\frac{\dot{f}_t^k}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^k}
 \frac{T_i^k-T_i^{k-1}}{\Delta z}
+\frac{\pi D_i}{A\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
+\frac{\rho_{\textrm{cat}}a}{\varepsilon_{\textrm{cat}}C_t^kC_p^k}
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \eta_i^kr_i^k(-\Delta H_{\!f,i}^k) \tag{1.1} \label{eq1}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```