# Eqn numbers in aligned environment

Tags: equations, align

I want to write an equation with multiple cases, but that needs multiple aligned columns within each case. I also want a left brace (of my choosing) on the left. Something like this works:

```
\begin{equation}
F = 
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
1.
& 2.
& \ &\text{First row} \\
3. 
& 4.
& \ &\text{Second row}
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
```

However, only one number is assigned to the group (simply the equation environment). I'd like to tag each individual row (of the aligned environment). is there a way to do this?

Comment: The answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10379/215) might be helpful

Comment: Also, you should be clear: do you want _separate_ equation numbers or _subequation_ numbers? i.e. 1,2 or 1.a,1.b?

Comment: @Seamus: I'm not sure how the link helps---in this case, I need an aligned environment within another. Re: separate or subequation, the ability to do both would be useful (not in the same block of equations), but not essential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load the **empheq** package and then write

```
\begin{empheq}[left={F=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
a&=b &&\quad\text{first} \\
c&=d &&\quad\text{second} \\
e&=f &&\quad\text{third}
\end{empheq}
```

It doesn't mix well with left equation numbers, though. But in any case right equation numbers are preferable.

In this particular case `align` is not well suited, because it gives too much spacing between columns.